# jquery to read list of objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a rest service which is called in front end using getjson and the response of the rest service is List where ClassName is a my class which has the required properties.

Can you say me on how to read the list and get properties of ClassName

Comment: So based on a json array that would look like `{"ClassName":"SomeClass", "properties":["prop1","prop2"]}` you want to get the properties `prop1` and `prop2` from `SomeClass` in you javascript? aka run `SomeClass.prop1` and `SomeClass.prop2`?  Where do you want these values put once you get them?

Comment: impossible to tell how to read what can't be seen... post example of response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should return your properties (if I got your question right, which is hard to tell):

```
$.getJSON('yourServiceUri', function(data){ 
    $.each(data, function(id, obj){ 
        $.each(obj, function(propName, value){
            console.log(propName + ": " + value);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer assumes that `data` is an array of objects. Just thought I'd make sure anyone unfamiliar with this type of code knows that.